# Condenser fan quits on a Goodman heat/air unit

Tags: central-air

I have an older Goodman heat and air outside unit. I can run the heat on it for awhile, sometimes 30 minutes sometimes 40 minutes and sometimes longer, but then the condenser fan just stops but the rest of the unit keeps running.

If I pull the main breaker outside by the unit and shut everything down, and then put the breaker right back in, it starts right up, fan and all, and runs fine for awhile, but it then does the same thing. I can also let it just sit for awhile without pulling the breaker and the fan will eventually kick back on and run fine, and does this cycle over and over the same way.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: A "Goodman" unit was previously sold under the Amana-Raytheon brand. You may have better luck searching for Amana Inc. Pre 1970's, Post 1970's Amana - a Raytheon Company, Post 1990's Amana - a Maytag company, 2000's Amana - Whirlpool ..... in HVAC "Amana® is a registered trademark of Maytag Corporation or its related companies and is used under license. All rights reserved." a Goodman Inc. Company - Now. Goodman seem's to have a good set of pdf's if you know your model. Good Luck. (I know Amana Inc, history, lived in Amana, Iowa 25 years.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I've edited your question so it's easier to read; you can re-edit it to add more details if you like.\

Comment: Has the fan been serviced? At that age the bearings may be dry and causing the motor to overheat. There are also start/run capacitors that could be failing, I usually check fan speeds with a tachometer to verify the motor is getting to speed, at more than a few minutes run time I would be looking at the run capacitor and the bearings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and No the fan has never been serviced but the motor is cool to the touch when it happens I talked to a tech yesterday and he said it sounds like a defrost mode on the unit did they have defrosts on these it’s probably 15 or more years old ?

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Ed.  The condenser fan motor itself is suspect.  Those motors operate under severe weather conditions resulting in a very reasonable life expectancy. Those bearing are factory sealed; nonservicable.   SOP replace the motor.